# Yii $criteria->addBetweenCondition not Working in CDbCriteria

Tags: php, yii

I want to get results of sender score between 1 to 10,So I have add this condtion.

```
   $criteria->addBetweenCondition('sender_score',$_GET['senderscore_start'],$_GET['senderscore_end']);
```

`sender_score` is my table field, senderscore_start and senderscore_end are only public variables.

My Search From Code:

```
<div class="row">       
    <?php echo $form->label($model,'senderscore_start'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'senderscore_start',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>100,'style'=>'width:300px;')); ?>      
</div>  
<div class="row">       
    <?php echo $form->label($model,'senderscore_end'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'senderscore_end',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>100,'style'=>'width:300px;')); ?>       
</div>
```

My Model Code:

```
public $senderscore_start;
public $senderscore_end;

array('senderscore_start,senderscore_end', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),

$criteria->addBetweenCondition('sender_score',$_GET['senderscore_start'],$_GET['senderscore_end']);`
```

But not showing results between 1,10 , can you look at this please! what's wrong with my code.
            `

Comment: Is this a GET form or a POST form? Since you are using `CActiveForm` to generate input fields, the field names will be something like `Model[senderscore_start]` , not plain `senderscore_start` (where `Model` is the name of your model class), therefore your code should be using `$_GET['Model']['senderscore_start']`.

Comment: this is GET form,and my model name is IpManager.

Comment: Then you need to pass `$_GET['IpManager']['senderscore_start']` to the criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this!

```
 $criteria->addBetweenCondition('sender_score',$_GET['IpManager']['senderscore_start'],$_GET['IpManager']['senderscore_end']);
```

Comment: Thanks very mcuh for replying me,

Answer (score 2):

You should not access any request variables like `$_GET` from inside your models. So the correct solution would be:

```
$criteria->addBetweenCondition('sender_score',$this->senderscore_start, $this->senderscore_end);
```

Comment: Request variables are not magically assigned to models - you should mention that OP needs to do mass-assignment or manual attribute assignment in the controller beforehand.

Comment: Well, the OP even added validation rules for these attributes. So i assumed, he already figured that out. But right: If not there already, you have to add a line like this to your controller action: `$model->attributes = $_GET['IPManager'];`